# Generics and inheritance... Getting around having to specify the <T> type?

Tags: c#, database, generics, reflection

Well, I've had to rewrite this as I've been down voted five times for giving too much detail... Go figure!

```
class BaseModel
{
    public T[] Get<T>()
    {
        // return array of T's
    }
    public T Find<T>(object param)
    {
        // return T based on param
    }
    public T New<T>()
    {
        // return a new instance of T
    }
}

class BaseRow
{
    private BaseModel _model;
    public BaseRow(SqlDataReader rdr, BaseModel model)
    {
        // populate properties of inheriting type using rdr column values
    }
    public void Save()
    {
        // calls _model.Save(this);
    }
}
```

I currently have a number of classes that inherit the BaseModel class. Each of the methods exposed by BaseModel will return an instance, or an array of instances of a type that inherits the BaseRow class.

At the moment, when calling the exposed methods on the BaseModel via an inheriting class, i.e.

```
using(DeviceModel model = new DeviceModel())
{
    DeviceRow row = model.Find<DeviceRow>(1);
    DeviceRow[] rows = model.Get<DeviceRow>();
    DeviceRow newRow = model.New<DeviceRow>();
}
```

I have to specify the  type (a class that inherits the BaseRow class), as the methods in BaseModel/BaseRow do not know/care what type they are, other than they inherit from BaseRow.

**What I would like to do is find a way to remove the need to specify the  without having to replicate code in every class that inherits BaseModel**, i.e.

```
class DeviceModel : BaseModel
{
    public DeviceRow Find(object param)
    {
        return this.Find<DeviceRow>(param);
    }
}
```

Note: Unfortunately I am unable to implement or use any third party solutions. That said, I have tried using Castle Active Record/nHibernate and to be honest, they are very big and heavy for what should be a very simple system.

Hopefully I haven't provided "too much" detail. If I have, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure we need all this code to answer your question? Can't you simplify it a bit (or a lot)?

Comment: Why not use LINQ2SQL? Seems to do exactly what you ask for.

Comment: The tricky problem for you is to find a minimal example that demonstrates your problem. Along the way, you might even solve your own problem!

Comment: I agree, i for one am simply not motivated enough to read it all, but if you could simplify it then i might have a useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I'd suggest making BaseModel a generic class.  In a situation of "can't win either way", the code you've removed to make others happy might have told me more about what you're doing (not a criticism by any stretch -  I appreciate your position).

```
class BaseModel<T>
{
    public virtual T[] Get()
    {
        // return array of T's
    }
    public virtual T Find(object param)
    {
        // return T based on param
    }
    public virtual T New()
    {
        // return a new instance of T
    }
}
```

That's your base, and then you have inheritors like:

```
class DeviceModel : BaseModel<Device>
{
    public override Device New()
    {
        return new Device();
    }
}
```

Now, any generic operations you define in DeviceModel will default to returning or using strongly typed Device.  Notice the virtual methods in the BaseModel class.  In the base class methods, you might provide some basic operations predicated upon using T's or something.  In sub-classes, you can define more specific, strongly typed behavior.

I'd also comment that you might want to pull back a little and consider the relationship of BaseModel and BaseRow.  It appears that you're defining a parallel inheritance hierarchy, which can tend to be a code smell (this is where more of your code might have come in handy -- I could be wrong about how you're using this).  If your ongoing development prospects are that you're going to need to add a FooRow every time you add a FooModel, that's often a bad sign.

Comment: Thanks Erik, your effort is highly appreciated. I can see why others ran when seeing my first attempt. This is an attempt to strongly define my database schema but make it flexible at the same time. BaseModel provides the connectivity and functions to allow me to easily read/write to my database. BaseRow aids by providing the methods that communicate with the underlying Model to write changes. ActiveRecord/nHibernate forced you to use the same object, which meant that a row was very heavy, when really it should just be a very simple class with the columns as properties.

Comment: I took a quick look at using <T> when defining the class. Most likely going to be the solution but will involve me rewriting a fair amount of my code, but I suppose, either way I would have had to do that anyway. Thanks ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a no go, unless you can help with something else? The BaseRow class needs an instance of the BaseModel. BaseModel needs a type when creating an instance, which means BaseRow would need to have a <T> set, but of course, being generics, it shouldn't care what type. I've tried using object, but that fails even compiling :( Any idea's? Cheers

Comment: I'd say that you look into the new constraint on generics.  The idea is that if you specify this constraint, you can declare new T().  Keep in mind, though, this only works if all of your T's have paramaterless constructors.